# How to get command name in HttpModule in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I need to block module (IHttpModule) logic based on command names. How to get it in OnEnter method?
private void OnEnter(object sender, EventArgs args)

Comment: Is this ASP.Net web forms? If so is this event registered for a button control?

Comment: Module is triggered before action on button as per my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, modules are ran before events, I was asking if this is a button event handler or other control... because I couldn't find OnEnter event for button controls in asp.net webforms.

Comment: This is kind of tracking double submit. Click the button and then module checks some label autogenerated and allows handler or not. I want to do exceptions for buttons that actually are not required for such behavior. Like you have command names and if it is "Save" then module checks otherwise it just skips and proceeds to handler.